# Glassfish shows default homepage instead of my web app welcome file

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm developping a web application using Netbeans 7 and Gassfish 3+ server

Actually, I've a problem to run my project 
There is no error but the browser shows me the default home page of the server and  not index.jsp

I specified index.jsp in web.xml :

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Any idea to resolve that problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Glassfish server homepage is usually shown if you don't have the application name (context root) in your path.

Your URL in browser should look like:

> http://localhost:8080/appname/index.jsp

replace *appname* with your applications name. This is normally the Netbeans project name. If you are not sure, look into the file:

> project-dir/web/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml

There you will find a tag `<context-root>`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Matt, I add the appName in glassfish-web.xml

But I found another problem with css due to changing the contextpath

To resolve it I replace ../ by pagecontext.request.contextPath in my jsp files like this :

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />
```